# Parsing XML files without using loops?

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I am parsing a bunch of large xml files using the `XML` package for the values of the variable "`varname`". The code I am using is:

```
library(XML)
a = xmlTreeParse("/path/filename.xml")
r = xmlRoot(a)
namelist = list()
for(i in 1:xmlSize(r)){namelist[[i]] <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(r[[i]])$varname)}
```

Since this is taking a long time to run, I tried parallel processing:

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()
namelist = list()
namelist <- foreach(i = 1:xmlSize(r)) %dopar% {namelist[[i]] <- xmlValue(xmlChildren(r[[i]])$varname)}
```

This is faster, but is still freezing up my machine for large enough files. Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: You are building a DOM tree for the whole document,
which is inefficient for large documents:
explicitly setting the `handlers` argument of 
`xmlTreeParse` to just extract the information you need and discard everything else may speed things up.

Comment: Vincent... Sorry I'm not very familiar with xml and am muddling along with R's documentation. Could you please provide sample code? Thanks.

Comment: Without any detail about what your data looks like, it is difficult to be more specific.
Here is one example from the documentation (slightly simplified):
`fileName <- system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package="XML");
r <- character(0);
f <- function(x, attrs) { r <<- c(r, xmlValue(x[[1]])); TRUE };
xmlTreeParse(fileName, handlers = list(variable=f), asTree=FALSE);
r`

Comment: @user702432: I have tidied up my all irrelevant posts further to your last edit. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than putting [solved] in the title of this post, you should write this up as an answer and accept it!

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered for more information. About [solved] in titles.

Answer (score 2):

*As stated by the original poster of the question:*

---

To anyone reading this post: the simplest solution would appear to the the `xmlToDataFrame` function in the `XML` library. It requires only minor tweaking about reading in the xml file in my case. Highly recommended. Apologies I found this out only after posting the question.